# Infinite Telescoping Sum: $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (X_i - X_{i-1})=$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

Let $(X_i)_{i \geq 0}$ be any countable sequence of numbers and suppose that a limit exists, so $$\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} X_i = x.$$

Consider  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (X_i - X_{i-1})$.

Is this telescoping sum given by $x-X_0$ or by $-X_0$ only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have, for $N \geq1$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - X_{i-1})=X_N-X_0
$$ then letting $N \to \infty$ gives

> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (X_i - X_{i-1})=x-X_0
> $$

since $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} X_i = x.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is what I first thought of. In my lecture notes concerning a related question however, it is written that 

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i - \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} X_{i+1} = X_0$, isn't this a contradiction? Or is here maybe implicitly directly used the assumption (we had there) that $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} X_i = 0$? Or is there a difference between $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (X_i - X_{i-1})$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i - \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_{i-1}$?

Comment: You are welcome! I think in your lecture notes, $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} X_i = 0$ is assumed. There is no contradiction. Thanks.

Comment: @user136457 For the last question, there is a definite difference between those two expressions. The first (the telescoping sum of the differences), the sum exists as long as the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{i \to \infty} X_i$ exists and is finite (not necessarily zero, although it can be). The second (difference between two summations) exists if and only if $\displaystyle \lim_{i \to \infty} X_i = 0$, because only in that circumstance does each summation converge. Otherwise you end up with an indeterminate $\infty - \infty$ form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the difference. This is very helpful!